# How to find an optimum number of processes in GridSearchCV( ..., n_jobs = ... )?

Tags: python, machine-learning, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, parallelism-amdahl

I'm wondering, which is better to use with **`GridSearchCV( ..., n_jobs = ... )`** to pick the best parameter set for a model, **`n_jobs = -1`** or **`n_jobs`** with a big number,
 like **`n_jobs = 30`** ?

Based on Sklearn documentation:

> `n_jobs = -1` means that the computation will be dispatched on all the
>   CPUs of the computer.

On my PC I have an Intel i3 CPU, which has 2 cores and 4 threads, so does that mean if I set **`n_jobs = -1`**, implicitly it will be equal to **`n_jobs = 2`** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *... does that mean if I set `n_jobs = -1`, implicitly it will be equal to `n_jobs = 2` ?*

### This one is easy :

python ( scipy / joblib inside a `GridSearchCV()` ) used to detect the number of CPU-cores, that is reasonable to schedule concurrent ( independent ) processes, given a request was done with an `n_jobs = -1` setting.

[image] Funny to see a 3-CPU-core?

In some virtualised-machine cases, that can synthetically emulate CPU / cores, the results are not as trivial as in your known Intel CPU / i3 case.

If in doubts, one can **test** this with a trivialised case ( on an indeed small data-set, not the full-blown model-space search ... ) and let the story go on to prove this.

```
import psutil;                  print( "{0:17s}{1:} CPUs PHYSICAL".format(
      "psutil:",
       psutil.cpu_count( logical = False ) ) )
pass;                           print( "{0:17s}{1:} CPUs LOGICAL".format(
      "psutil:",
       psutil.cpu_count( logical = True  ) ) )
...
```

A similar host-platform "self-detection" may report more details for different systems / settings:

```
'''
sys:             linux 
                 3.6.1 (default, Jun 27 2017, 14:35:15)  .. [GCC 7.1.1 20170622 (Red Hat 7.1.1-3)]

multiprocessing: 1 CPU(s)
psutil:          1 CPUs PHYSICAL
psutil:          1 CPUs LOGICAL
psutil:          psutil.cpu_freq(  per_cpu = True  ) not able to report. ?( v5.1.0+ )
psutil:          5.0.1
psutil:          psutil.cpu_times( per_cpu = True  ) not able to report. ?( vX.Y.Z+ )
psutil:          5.0.1
psutil:          svmem(total=1039192064, available=257290240, percent=75.2, used=641396736, free=190361600, active=581107712, inactive=140537856, buffers=12210176, cached=195223552, shared=32768)
numexpr:         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numexpr'.
joblib:          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'joblib'.
sklearn/joblib:  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.externals.joblib' 
'''
```

---

Or

```
''' [i5]
>>> numexpr.print_versions()
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Numexpr version:   2.5
NumPy version:     1.10.4
Python version:    2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (32-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 14:07:41) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
AMD/Intel CPU?     True
VML available?     True
VML/MKL version:   Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 11.3.1 Product Build 20151021 for 32-bit applications
Number of threads used by default: 4 (out of 4 detected cores)
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
'''
```

---

> *... which is better to use with GridSearchCV to pick the best parameter set for a model, 
> `n_jobs = -1` or `n_jobs` with a big number like `n_jobs = 30` ?*

### There is no easy "*One-Size-Fits-All*" answer on this :

The Scikit tools ( and many other followed this practice ) used to spawn, on **`n_jobs`** directive being used, a required amount of concurrent process-instances ( so as to escape from shared GIL-lock stepping - read more on this elsewhere if interested in details ).

This process-instantiation is not cost-free ( both time-wise, i.e. spending a respectfull amount of the **`[TIME]`**-domain costs, but also space-wise, i.e. spending at least an **`n_jobs`**-times the RAM-allocations of the single python process-instance in **`[SPACE]`**-domain ).

Given this, your fight is a battle against a dual-edged sword.

An attempt to "underbook" **CPU** will let ( some ) CPU-cores possibly idling.
An attempt to "overbook" **RAM**-space will turn your performance worse than expected, as virtual-memory will turn operating system swapping, which turns your Machine Learning-scaled data-access times from **`~ 10+[ns]` more than 100,000 x slower `~ 10+ [ms]`** which is hardly what one will be pleased at.

The overall effects of **`n_jobs = a_reasonable_amount_of_processes`** is subject of [**Amdahl's Law** ( the re-formulated one, not an add-on overhead-naive version )](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3), so there will be a practical optimality peak ( a maximum ) of how many CPU-cores will help to improve one's processing intentions, beyond of which the overhead-costs ( sketched for both the `[TIME]`- and `[SPACE]`-domains above ) will actually deteriorate any potential positive impact expectations.

Having used **`RandomForestRegressor()`** on indeed large data-sets in production, I can tell you the **`[SPACE]`**-domain is your worse of the  enemies in trying to grow `n_jobs` any farther and none system-level tuning will ever overcome this boundary ( so more and more ultra-low latency RAM and more and more ( real ) CPU-cores is the only practical recipe for going into indeed any larger `n_jobs` computing plans ).

Answer (score 5):

An additional simpler answer by Prof. Kevyn Collins-Thompson, from course Applied Machine Learning in Python:

If I have 4 cores in my system, `n_jobs = 30` (30 as an example) will be the same as `n_jobs = 4`. So no additional effect

> So the maximum performance that can be obtained always is using `n_jobs = -1`